# Elfinder minifying issue

Tags: javascript, minify, jake, elfinder

A have a little problem with minifying elFinder. I was followed official guide:

https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Build-and-compress-elfinder-from-source

But I'm stuck here:

```
martin@BlackJack:~/elFinder>jake -C ./build elfinder --trace
jake aborted.

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/jake/bin/cli.js:72:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

...and I have no idea how to solve this. I'm using MacOS X 10.7.5. Can you help me a bit please?

Comment: Anyone figure this one out?